# How to popup a javascript alert box with textbox inside to update mysql table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm making a site that lets people login, buy stuff from the store, etc, I am trying to make it where moderators can change and update their credits by clicking a  link and make a popup alert box thing pop up saying to type in how many credits to give them in the popup box, then click "Ok" and update the mysql table with the new amount, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create the popup effect that you wanted you could use prompt() which is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).

Using:

```
function giveCredits(user) {
    var amount = prompt('Please enter the amount of creidts you wish to give to ' + user,100);
    SQLCreditfunction(user,amount);   
}
```

You should be able to create the desired effect. SQLCreditfunction will be a function to insert the value into the database.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use JavaScript's prompt function which provides a text box to enter value after getting the value from the user you can make an ajax request to sever to update the new amount in the database.

Something like this:-

First add jQuery file in your page.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="updateAmount(itemId);">Click here to update amount</a>
<script>
    function updateAmount(itemId){
        amount = prompt('Enter new amount', 0);
        $.ajax({
            url: updateAmount.php,
           data: {"amount": amount, "id": itemId},
           success: function(data){
               alert("Amount updated successfully.");
           }
        });
    }
</script>
```